# datepicker displays when submit form' button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I do have a problem with my MVC razor form, it has two jQuery DatePickers in order to let the user select the start date and the finish date for a specific event,
at the load of the form the datepicker  the datepickers work fine (let the user to select the dates) but when the user clicks the button to submit the info, it displays the first datepicker again and doesn´t send the info to the due MVC controller, could you tell me what is the problem?

I display the datepicker in two different `html.editorFor`

```
 $("#fechaInicio").datepicker
 $("#fechaFin").datepicker
```

and the code for the datepickers is

```
 $("#fechaInicio").datepicker({
            dayNamesMin: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mie", "Jue", "Vie", "Sab"],
            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showAnim: "fold",
            showClose: true         
        });

        $("#fechaFin").datepicker({
            dayNamesMin: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mie", "Jue", "Vie", "Sab"],
            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showAnim: "fold",
            showClose: true
        });
```

the user is allowed to select the date when click a checkbox

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                Fecha Inicio Capacitación
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Radio button for following text input" id="chkInicio">
                    </span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fec_ini_mod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "fechaInicio", @disabled = "disabled" } })
                </div>
            </div>

<div class="col-xs-5">
                        Fecha Fin Capacitación
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Radio button for following text input" id="chkFin">
                            </span>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fec_fin_mod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "fechaFin" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

```
$("#chkInicio").on('change', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("#fechaInicio").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#fechaFin").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#idCfecha").val(1);
            } else {
                $("#fechaInicio").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#fechaInicio").val("");
                $("#fechaFin").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#fechaFin").val("");
                $("#idCfecha").val(0);
            }
        });
```

and finally the code of the button

```
<input type="button" value="Registrar Modificaciones" id="btn-modificar" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />

 $("#btn-modificar").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#fechaInicio").datepicker("hide");
            $("#fechaFin").datepicker("hide");
            this.focus();
            $("#idNIT").val(proveedor);
```

Comment: Is there a fiddle or another method to replicate or test this? Do you see any errors or alerts in console when you submit the form?

Comment: Unable to replicate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vdg363zm/ FYI, in your button code, you have `this.focus()`, I switched ti to `$(this).focus()`.

Comment: @Twisty sorry, there are two inputs in the form, I just added the second one

Comment: Updated my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vdg363zm/2/ Still unable to replicate the issue as you described it.

Comment: I don´t get it but delete the lines: $("#fechaInicio").datepicker
 $("#fechaFin").datepicker and works fine, thanks for the time.